# Solving the continuity equation for a given mass-density

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, density, differential-equations

Given a smooth and time-dependent [mass density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density) $\rho(t)>0$ which is spatially constant in 3-dimensional Euclidean space. Let's further assume the [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation#Differential_form)

$$\dot\rho+\text{div}(\vec{j})=0$$

with an unknown current $\vec{j}(x,y,z,t)$. How do I derive a (the) current $\vec{j}$ from this data? Is there a sort of general solution?

EDIT: So I have found the solution

$$ \vec{j} = -\frac{\dot\rho}{3}\,\vec{r}+\vec{c}\,h(t)$$

where $h(t)$ is a function of time only, $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$ and $\vec{c}$ a constant. Are there further solutions?

Comment: 1 equation for 3 unknowns : that doen't seem very promising for a unique solution unless $j$ only has 1 independent component, but then integration should be straightforward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without additional information, it is impossible to obtain a unique answer. The reason is a [theorem by Helmholtz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) which says that **a vector field is uniquely specified once its divergence and curl are given** (plus some condition on possible discontinuities at finite distances and asymptotic behavior of the fields). By giving  only  the divergence of a field is equivalent to specity it *within an arbitrary solenoidal field*.